# React Native useState<Component>() syntax

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm followint a tutorial where the following syntax for `React.useState` is in use:

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, User } from 'firebase/auth' 
const [user, setUser] = React.useState<User>();
```

When I implement this code in my React Native app and run Expo I get the message that `()` is an unexpected token.

What does it mean? I studied different React guides to find a explanation for this but they did not explain the combination of `useState` and `<>`.

Comment: This is typescript syntax. Don't use it in plain javascript/jsx.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a `type` called `User`, this is for Typescript.
Your file is in Javascript, therefore the syntax would be:

```
const [user, setUser] = React.useState(undefined);
```